# How to run v2ray for installed apps, too

Tags: networking, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 23.4 for desktop and vmess protocol with v2ray client. I can run it with `./v2ray run` and by changing Firefox network settings I have an active VPN for browsing. But I also need my traffic for other installed apps to go through the VPN. For example, when working in a terminal, or using Telegram Desktop, I need an active VPN. In Windows, the v2ray client automatically brings the whole traffic via VPN. How to do it in Ubuntu?